# Object Oriented vs. dotted notation

Tags: javascript

I *know* that the following example is used to instantiate an object, but I'm trying to figure out when I would ever use it:

```
function Person(){
  this.age = 0
}

var p = new Person()
```

I'm old school, but the way that I write JavaScript is like this:

```
var person = {}
person.age = 0
person.myMethod = function() {
}
```

I guess I never need two instances of a person object. I think what I'm doing is applying old school thinking to JavaScript's dotted notation and I'm never truly using objects in any of my programming.

Could it be that if you were to come up with an example where you use objects, and I were tasked with solving the same use case, then I would have solved it procedurally? Or is there a use case where object oriented is clearly the better solution?

Comment: Why not use the new ES6 class syntax? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Dot / bracket notation, called [object property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), nor object instances are new javascript mechanisms. If you don't need multiple instances of some object then the second one is fine. But sometimes you might want multiple objects to have the same methods and similar properties. Like having 40 Person objects, would you rather write each object explicitly or just define one constructor / methods / etc and simply create a new instance each time you need one.

Comment: Answers to this question are mostly opinion based. It totally depends on the case at hands..

Comment: I agree that it's opinion based, but it's sort of foundational as to how to write JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you never need two instances of a person object, then there isn't a huge need for ES6 classes, or functions and new, or `function.prototype`  The value of new (and all the related mechanisms) comes in when you need to:

- have multiple objects of a given type
- Figure out whether a given object is a given type
- Use inheritance
- Extend an already existing type and see those extensions reflected in already-existing objects

If you never need to do any of those things, then using object literals and dot notation to construct your objects seems entirely reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

There are valid [performance concerns](https://gist.github.com/twokul/9501770) for using one rather than the other, but they are strongly related to the way JS runtimes are implemented... If you can declare the "shape" of your objects through syntax the compilers can optimize, mutating objects bails out automatically...

Your question is mostly opinion oriented, however recent JS features tend to favor a "functional" style in which you try not to mutate objects, in your example :

```
const person = {
     age: 10,
     myMethod() {}
}
```

Rather than the dot notation.

Please note that using the lexical context `this` is merely passing an implicit argument, this can also be done in closure or explicitly.

Using closure means creating a new function for each instance of your entity, which has a cost obviously, passing explicitly (has first argument usually) means you cannot use dot notation and using prototype will only create one instance of the function but will have costs in resolving the function through the prototype chain.

```
// closure
const name = "john";
const person = { 
    name, 
    meet ( other ) { console.log(name + " says hello to " + other.name); }
};

// passing explicitly
function meet ( p1, p2 ) {

    console.log(p1.name + " says hello to " + p2.name);

}


// using the prototype with the class syntax
class Person {
    constructor (name) { this.name = name; }
    meet (other) { console.log(this.name + " says hello to " + other.name); }
}
```